# Get some parameters using Tensorflow

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, scikit-learn, model

```
a=df5['dbh']
b=df5['age']
y=np.array(a.values.tolist())
X=np.array(b.values.tolist())
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.plot(X, y, "o")
import random
a=tf.Variable(random.random())
b=tf.Variable(random.random())
c=tf.Variable(random.random())
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

def compute_loss():
    y_pred = a / (1 + ( b / X ) **c)
    loss=tf.reduce_mean((y-y_pred) **2)
    return loss

def accuracy():
    y_pred = a/(1+(b / X)**c)
    r2=r2_score(y, y_pred)
    return r2

def accuracy2():
    y_pred = a/(1+(b / X)**c)
    rmse=mean_squared_error(y, y_pred)**0.5
    return rmse  
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.07)

for i in range(100):

    optimizer.minimize(compute_loss, var_list=[a, b, c])
    if i % 100 == 99:
           print(i, 'a:', a.numpy(), 'b:', b.numpy(), 'c:', c.numpy(),'loss:', 
           compute_loss().numpy(), 'r2:', accuracy(), 'rmse:', accuracy2())
```

Hi, I want to extract some parameters, a, b, c.
I write down the code but, I got an error:

```
ValueError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-032507975e53> in <module>
      3         if i % 100 == 99:
      4                print(i, 'a:', a.numpy(), 'b:', b.numpy(), 'c:', c.numpy(),'loss:', compute_loss().numpy(), 
----> 5                     'r2:', accuracy(), 'rmse:', accuracy2())

<ipython-input-45-6e5f54eee4c0> in accuracy()
      6 def accuracy():
      7         y_pred = a/(1+(b / X)**c)
----> 8         r2=r2_score(y, y_pred)
      9         return r2
     10 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_regression.py in r2_score(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight, multioutput)
    674     -3.0
    675     """
--> 676     y_type, y_true, y_pred, multioutput = _check_reg_targets(
    677         y_true, y_pred, multioutput)
    678     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_regression.py in _check_reg_targets(y_true, y_pred, multioutput, dtype)
     88     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
     89     y_true = check_array(y_true, ensure_2d=False, dtype=dtype)
---> 90     y_pred = check_array(y_pred, ensure_2d=False, dtype=dtype)
     91 
     92     if y_true.ndim == 1:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    661 
    662         if force_all_finite:
--> 663             _assert_all_finite(array,
    664                                allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
    665 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
    101                 not allow_nan and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
    102             type_err = 'infinity' if allow_nan else 'NaN, infinity'
--> 103             raise ValueError(
    104                     msg_err.format
    105                     (type_err,
```

**Error:**

```
 Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').
```

Could you please give some solutions for the problem? The error message is above. the line containing error be checked. But, I can't understand the error message. please give me solutions.
Thank you very much
Best regards,

Comment: Can you show us which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Thank you for your consideration. I added the instruction about the error.

Comment: If you trace back the error, it's basically suggesting that there is a NaN or infinite value in ``y_pred = a/(1+(b / X)**c)``. Does X has a zero value perhaps?

Comment: No, The data doesn't contain the zero value...